# User Authorization with CASL library share between backend and frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, casl

I am looking at a way to implement authorization in both frontend(React) and backend(Node.js, Koa, GraphQL). I have stumbled across the casl package: https://github.com/stalniy/casl .

Though the backend authorization seems pretty straightforward to me, what I don't get is how can I share my authorization rules from the backend to my frontend. One medium post suggested JWT tokens. How would one go about doing that with a JWT token ?

https://medium.com/dailyjs/casl-and-cancan-permissions-sharing-between-ui-and-api-5f1fa8b4bec

Comment: you can share rules anyway you want. This is just an array of objects after all. The easiest way is to return them in response body on login request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems CASL has 2 function to achieve this, packRules and unpackRules.

As per documentation in the backend you can do:

```
import { packRules } from '@casl/ability/extra';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { defineRulesFor } from '../services/appAbility';

app.post('/session', (req, res) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({
    id: req.user.id,
    rules: packRules(defineRulesFor(req.user))
  }, 'jwt secret', { expiresIn: '1d' });

  res.send({ token });
});
```

And in the frontend you do:

```
import { unpackRules } from '@casl/ability/extra'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import ability from '../services/appAbility';

export default class LoginComponent {
  login(params) {
    return http.post('/session')
      .then((response) => {
        const token = jwt.decode(response.token);
        ability.update(unpackRules(token.rules))
      });
  }
}
```

https://stalniy.github.io/casl/v4/en/api/casl-ability-extra

Comment: Where do you get `defineRulesFor` function?

Comment: P.S. turns out if you already have `ability` instance you can just use `packRules(ability.rules)`